# Which preposition to use with "enhancements"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

When I want to talk about enhancing something, which is the correct preposition to use?

To me, as a non-native speaker, all of the following options sound acceptable, but I would probably use the first one:

1. enhancements ***of*** sth.
2. enhancements ***to*** sth.
3. enhancements ***for*** sth.

To give some context: I'm writing about an algorithm that can be enhanced in many ways by changing or adding instructions. Depending on the domain, these enhancements may but need not improve the results.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/57998/14666

Comment: Any preposition is acceptable depending on what follows it and also very much on the context.

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Comment: May be better posted on [ell.se]

Comment: @Kris The context here is clear: the object of the preposition must be the thing enhanced.  Ngram tells us that the top four candidate are (in order) *to*, *of*, *in*, and *for*.  Certainly *except* would not be acceptable here. The acceptability of a preposition depends crucially on what precedes it.  Some words license only specific prepositions.

Comment: @deadrat The Q does not confine itself to the OP's context alone.

Comment: @Kris And what do you think the OP means when he writes "When I want to talk about enhancing something...."?

Comment: @Kris: is this nitpickery really necessary?

Comment: Griddo, yes. It helps you if you are amenable to help.

Comment: Okay, so first of all: your first four comments could just have been combined into one (especially the 3rd and 4th ...). As for the ELL community: I didn't know about it, but there are plenty of questions like mine on the *english* community, so I thought it would fit in. And regarding your linked post: yes, it is related, but the accepted answer doesn't apply here, in my opinion.

Comment: @Griddo Usually, someone flagging a related question is intending it to be helpful: it may or may not answer your specific question, but person thinks it might be helpful to you. So please do not complain about people trying to help you. As regards ELL, the same applies. Yes, there may be lots of similar Qs here - but there are also lots of Qs that are referred to ELL.  *This* site states that it "is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts."  Please respect that. Cont'd ...

Comment: ... cont'd  Lastly, Kris's first comment stated that the answer depends "on what follows" - that is confirmed in the Answer below from HerbCaudill.  If you can't be bothered to answer relevant Qs from those seeking to help you, then ...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All options listed are correct in this context. I'd be more likely to use option (3) when the object is the *purpose* of the enhancements...

> This version of the algorithm includes enhancements for faster searching.

... or the *context* of the enhancements.

> This version of the software includes enhancements for Android and iOS.

The first option, e.g. *enhancements **to** the algorithm*, is much more common. (And it's only the word that fits ['enhancements * the algorithm'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enhancements+*+the+algorithm&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cenhancements%20to%20the%20algorithm%3B%2Cc0) on Ngram.)

Comment: Note that if you choose the "English (2019)" corpus for the Google n-gram query, you do get _both_ "to" and "of", and, interestingly, "of" - while historically less frequent - seems to be gaining ground: [n-gram link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enhancements+*+the+algorithm&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3)